# How to chain JSP response to Servlet request

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jsonp

I have a situation where I have to generate a lot of HTML and then return it as a string JSONP style. So the eventual HTTP response will actually be javascript text like this:

`myglobaljavascriptcallbackfunction('`<HTML here>`');`

Since the HTML is complex, the only sane way to construct it is with a JSP. So what I would like to do is take the HTML output of the JSP and pipe it to a servlet which can then wrap the HTML with the necessary javascript.

Below is my best guess so far. No luck - the HTTP response from the Servlet is `myglobaljavascriptcallbackfunction('');` without any of the JSP's HTML.

**JSP**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<jsp:forward page="/MyServlet" />
<div>
   <span>Imagine some really complicated stuff here</span>
<div>
```

**Servlet**

```
protected void doGet(...) {

    String pre = "myglobaljavascriptcallbackfunction('";
    String post = "');";

    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    out.write(pre.getBytes());

    // transfer request to response
    InputStream in = request.getInputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; 
    int count = 0; 
    while ((count = in.read(buf)) > 0) { 
        out.write(buf, 0, count);
        // TODO: escape single quote chars
    }

    out.write(post.getBytes());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`<jsp:include>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref2020.html) if you want to **include** Servlet response in JSP.

Use [`RequestDispatcher#include()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) if you want to **include** JSP response in Servlet. This one is what you want. You should however only need to change the XHR request URL to point to the Servlet instead of the JSP.

---

Note: you have a potential character encoding problem with the `getBytes()` call which is implicitly using the platform default character encoding.

Comment: This is closer, but it immediately dumps the HTML to the ServletResponse. I need to be able to process the output of the JSP before it is written to the Response to remove white space and escape certain characters since the HTML will all be put into a javascript string (btw I'm using JSONP here not XHR)

Comment: Use a `Filter` with a whitespace trimeer or a `File` or `URLConnection` in servlet to open JSP locally. Read "XHR" as "Client". Source of request actually doesn't matter. I was just expecting JS/ajax (XHR).